# Erro ao importar números com decimais no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando importar uma coluna de decimais em csv (parte de um dataset) através da função `read_delim`. Porém, as colunas com números decimais (separados por vírgula no dataset original) estão vindo como números inteiros.

Ex:

- 175,60 aparece como 17560
- 98,6851 aparece como 986851

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Comment: Tente usar o argumento `dec = ","`

Comment: A função `read_delim` (e suas irmãs `read_csv`, `read_csv2` e `read_tsv`) não possui o argumento `dec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `read_delim` não é capaz de lidar com números com vírgula. Utilize a função `read.csv` com o argumento `dec=","`:

```
read.csv(file="arquivo.csv", dec=",", sep=";")
```

Note que usei também o argumento `sep=";"` acima. Desta forma, estou assumindo que o separador de colunas no teu arquivo é o caractere `;`. Se for uma marca de tabulação, utilize `sep="\t"`.

Comment: deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Se é um ficheiro produzido em países onde as decimais são marcadas com `","` e o separador de colunas é o `";"`, então `read.csv2` já tem esses valores para os argumentos `dec` e `sep`.